# Clearing iOS CoreData database prevents subsequent updates

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

The functionality in my iPad app requires that occasionally I clear down the entire coredata database.  I do this as follows:

```
+(BOOL)clearEntireDB
{
    // Empty all collections

    NSArray* stores = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"ServerToken",@"Client",@"User",@"Form",@"Company",@"Contact",@"Response",@"Image",@"Thumbnail",@"SearchIndex",@"Tag",@"Literature", nil];

    BOOL rc=YES;
    for (int i=0;i<stores.count;i++)
    {
        if (rc==YES)
        {
            NSString* storeName = (NSString*)[stores objectAtIndex:i];
            rc=[HPSDbUtilities clearStore:storeName];
        }
    }

    if (rc==YES)
    {
    // Now need to delete all files in the document folder
        rc = [HPSFileHelper removeAllDocumentFiles];
    }


    return rc;
}
+(BOOL)clearStore:(NSString*)storeName
{
    BOOL rc=NO;

    @try{

        NSLog(@"HPSDbUtilities::clearStore %@",storeName);

        HPSAppDelegate* appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        NSManagedObjectContext * context = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;
        NSFetchRequest * fetch = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        [fetch setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:storeName inManagedObjectContext:context]];
        NSArray * result = [context executeFetchRequest:fetch error:nil];
        for (id record in result)
            [context deleteObject:record];

        NSError* error;

        if ([context save:&error] == YES)
        {
            NSLog(@"HPSDbUtilities::clearStore SAVED"); 
        }else {
            NSLog(@"HPSDbUtilities::clearStore NOT saved"); 
        }
        rc=YES;

    }@catch (NSException * e) {

        NSLog(@"clearStore Exception: %@", e);
        rc=NO;
    }

    return rc;
}
```

The app has a secondary thread which is keeping the core data db in sync with the web.  When clearing down the entire db I stop this secondary thread.  Once the db is cleared I start the secondary thread again.

All processing within the secondary thread works fine until I clear the DB.  The secondary thread save processing then starts failing with the following error:

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134030 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 134030.)" UserInfo=0x261c10 {NSAffectedStoresErrorKey=(
    "<NSSQLCore: 0xfe91310> (URL: file://localhost/var/mobile/Applications/3013185E-8171-4A1F-9E1F-6A02E7664510/Documents/Model.sqlite)"
), NSUnderlyingError=0x261b90 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 4.)", NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Applications/3013185E-8171-4A1F-9E1F-6A02E7664510/Documents/Model.sqlite}
```

The secondary thread code is spread across several classes so I can't really show it all here, but it is straightforward and simply creates MOCs, updates records and saves the MOC.

Can anyone shed any light on this problem?